# filter a result with a csv file

Tags: powershell, csv, import, filter

Basically, i have a script that scans the message tracking logs, it checks every 15 minutes through the last hour of logs looking for large amounts of email in a short amount of time.  I know how to filter with -gt and -notlike and all that, but i want the script to check a csv for the values that i want filtered.  for instance there are some people that we expect to send large amounts of emails in a short time, i need a csv exceptions list.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"
add-pssnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2007
add-pssnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin

$Now= Get-Date
$start= $Now.AddHours(-1)
#$end= $Now.AddHours(-1)

$Senders = ("bumailhub1","bumailhub2" | Get-MessageTrackingLog -resultsize unlimited -      Start "$start" -End "$Now" -EventId SEND | Select-Object ServerHostname,EventId,RecipientCount,Sender,MessageSubject,ConnectorId | where {$_.Connectorid -eq "Outbound new (Stucheck out)"})


********Right here below is where i need it to check for a csv exceptions list, which will contain a list of email addresses that are under the column "Name", and again when creating $csvmaker


$report = $senders | Group-Object Sender | Sort-Object Count -Descending | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 50 -and $_.Name -NOTLIKE "MicrosoftExchange*"} | Select-object Count, Name
$mailing1 = $report | ConvertTo-HTML | Set-Content c:\TEMP\Date_$((get-date).tostring("MMddyyyy"))_Time_$((get-date).tostring("HHmmss"))_Users_Over_100PERLast2Hour.htm

$exceptions = Import-Csv C:\TEMP\CSVS\Exceptions\Exceptions.csv

$csvmaker = $senders | Group-Object Sender | Sort-Object Count -Descending | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 100 -and $_.Name -NOTLIKE "MicrosoftExchange*"} | Select-object Count, Name
$csvmade =  $csvmaker | ConvertTo-CSV | Set-Content c:\TEMP\CSVS\Users_Over_100PERLast2Hour.csv

$mailing1
$mailing2 = $report | ConvertTo-Html
$subjectreport = $senders | Group-Object MessageSubject | Sort-Object Count -Descending | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 50 -and $_.Name -NOTLIKE "MicrosoftExchange*"} | Select-object Count, Name
$subjectreportemail = $subjectreport | ConvertTo-Html

$head = Get-Content C:\TEMP\files\head.htm
$report1 = Get-Content C:\TEMP\files\report1.htm
$report2 = Get-Content C:\TEMP\files\report2.htm

If ($report | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 100})
{
$Sender = "mailhub_issues@mydomain.com"
$SMTPClient = new-object System.Net.Mail.smtpClient
$SMTPClient.host = "mysmtp.mydomain.com"
$MailMessage = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$Address = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("1@mydomain")
$Address2 = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("2@mydomain")
$Address3 = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("3@mydomain")
$Address4 = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("4@mydomain")
$Address5 = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("5@mydomain")
$Address6 = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("6@mydomain")
$Address7 = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("7@mydomain")
$MailMessage.Subject = "SPAM EMAIL ALERT"
$MailMessage.Body = $head + $report1 + $subjectreportemail + $report2 + $mailing2
$MailMessage.Sender = $Sender
$MailMessage.From = $Sender
$MailMessage.To.add($Address)
#$MailMessage.To.add($Address2)
#$MailMessage.To.add($Address3)
#$MailMessage.To.add($Address4)
#$MailMessage.To.add($Address5)
#$MailMessage.To.add($Address6)
$MailMessage.To.add($Address7)
$MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true
$SMTPClient.Send($MailMessage)



}
$ChkFile = "c:\TEMP\CSVS\Users_Over_100PERLast2Hour.csv"
$FileExists = (Test-Path $ChkFile -PathType Leaf)

If ($FileExists)
{

$Sender = "mailhub_issues@mydomain"
$SMTPClient = new-object System.Net.Mail.smtpClient
$SMTPClient.host = "mysmtp.mydomain.com"
$MailMessage = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$Address = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("1@mydomain")
$Address2 = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("2@mydomain")
$Address3 = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("3@mydomain")
$Address4 = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("4@mydomain")
$Address5 = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("5@mydomain")
$Address6 = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("6@mydomain")
$Address7 = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("7@mydomain")
$att = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($ChkFile)
$MailMessage.Subject = "Disabled Mailboxes"
$MailMessage.Body = "Enclosed is a CSV file containing a list of the users who have had there mailboxes disabled as a result of too many email in a short time"
$MailMessage.Attachments.Add($att)
#$MailMessage.Body = $head + $report1 + $subjectreportemail + $report2 + $mailing2
$MailMessage.Sender = $Sender
$MailMessage.From = $Sender
$MailMessage.To.add($Address)
#$MailMessage.To.add($Address2)
#$MailMessage.To.add($Address3)
#$MailMessage.To.add($Address4)
#$MailMessage.To.add($Address5)
#$MailMessage.To.add($Address6)
$MailMessage.To.add($Address7)
$MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true
#$Attachment = $mailing
#$MailMessage.Attachements.Add($Attachment)
$SMTPClient.Send($MailMessage)
$att.Dispose()
import-csv c:\TEMP\CSVS\Users_Over_100PERLast2Hour.csv | foreach {disable-mailbox $_.Name -confirm:$false}
Move-Item c:\TEMP\CSVS\Users_Over_100PERLast2Hour.csv c:\TEMP\CSVS\OLD\Date_$((get-date).tostring("MMddyyyy"))_Time_$((get-date).tostring("HHmmss"))_Users_Over_100PERLast2Hour.csv

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read those senders from a simple text file:

```
$whitelistedSenders = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\sender_whitelist.txt'
```

If you must use a CSV, extract just the values of the sender name column:

```
$whitelistedSenders = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\sender_whitelist.csv' `
  | % { $_.'Sender Name' }
```

Then process only those senders not contained in the whitelist:

```
$subjectreport = $senders `
  | ? { $whitlistedSenders -notcontains $_.Name } `
  | Group-Object MessageSubject `
  | Sort-Object Count -Descending `
  | ? { $_.Count -gt 50 -and $_.Name -notlike "MicrosoftExchange*" } `
  | select Count, Name
```

Comment: If you put the `|` symbol at the end of the line you don't have to use the line continuation character. While the approach you use looks nice I've been bitten a few too many times where some extra whitespace gets in after the line continuation char and that throws off PowerShell.

Comment: @KeithHill My editor is configured to auto-remove trailing spaces on save. ;) I prefer to wrap lines this way, because I can immediately see where a command/pipeline is continued from the previous line.

Comment: i tried the above ideas but both of them seem to filter out all the results.  all the variables in my script have the right values until it hits the  ? { $whitlistedSenders -notcontains $_.Name } ` which then the results become none.  this seems to filter out all the results.  any other ideas?  The variable pulling from the csv or txt file do get the correct values out of the file though.

Comment: What is the output of `$whitelistedSenders.GetType()` and `($senders|%{$_.Name}).GetType()`? What do you get when you run `Compare-Object $($senders|%{$_.Name}) $whitelistedSenders -Include`?